# What the meaning of word reconciliation in react's reconciliation algorithm

Tags: reactjs

I'm curious about the word **reconciliation** which react use to describe their algorithm heuristically generate minimum operation sets in tree diff.

I'm not a native English speaker. I found this word is origin from the Bible. But what the actual meaning ?

Comment: This is off-topic, and belongs on [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com). (but looking up in a dictionary also helps: "the action of making one view or belief compatible with another.": here, not view or belief, but tree structure)

Answer (score 1):

Reconciliation is a phase where reactjs puts together your react application when rendering. During this phase it decides what parts of the DOM to keep and what parts to throw away.

Comment: Thant you ! I think i got it ... When react transform current virtual dom to next virtual dom, a heuristic algorithm called is reconciliation is used to find minimal operations.  The name reconciliation means sync. or "solve conflict become harmony".

Answer (score 0):

The “reconciliation ” algorithm in React is how the decision to re-render the item is made. In the browser, DOM manipulation is costly and time consuming, both in mounting and unmounting. Part of what makes Respond so successful is its algorithm of reconciliation.

In short, it closely watches for discrepancies and, if necessary, just changes the DOM and attempts to update only the sections that need to be updated.